# sort JSON data and get top n records

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, optimization

I have a json data of around millions of records. I have to do a simple but tricky functionality.

> What I have to do?

**I have to gather top 10 most appeared item from that json with it's count. by most appeared, I mean the most count of the item in json. I am not sure yet, how I will go with count, I mean I can add it to same json obejct as property.**

> Here is what I did so far.

```
//my origional json, it's too big but adding some portion of it.
var jsonData = [    
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "#5"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "#1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "#2"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "#8"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "#1"
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "#10" 
  },  
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "#2"
  }];    

var top10Data = [];

//geting top 10 items
function getTop10Data() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i <= 20) {
        top10Data.push(getTop1Data());
        i++;
    }

    return true;
}

//getting top 1 data that has max count in json
function getTop1Data() {
    var store = jsonData, distribution = {}, max = 0, result = [];

    store.forEach(function (a) {
        distribution[a] = (distribution[a] || 0) + 1;
        if (distribution[a] > max) {
            max = distribution[a];
            result = [a];
            return;
        }
        if (distribution[a] === max) {
            result.push(a);
        }
    });

    //remove this item with it's all occurences, and push it to top10Data
    removeData(result); 

    return result;
}

//remove items from origional json. but this is not working properly as it removes only one item from top
function removeData(result) {
    var length = jsonData.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (jsonData[i].toppings === result[0].toppings) {
            jsonData.splice(jsonData[i], 1);            
        }
    }
}
```

> My question.

**I think the way I am going is not proper, is there any better approach to handle this situation. and if mine approach is ok, what I am missing in current code.**

any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the actual input you're dealing with, and the desired output?

Comment: actual input is too large to include. I can add some part of it.

Comment: Hey, why are you using a function just to create a sub array.. You can use "array.slice"  easily..

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example of your desired output? Do you want an array of the most common elements, without duplicates, or what?

Comment: @PranbirSarkar well, I though it will make it easy to operate.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, that's true. an array of most common items with it's count.

Comment: This is most certainly what a database is for. Don't try to manage the data in-memory...

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am not sure yet, how I will go with count, I mean I can add it to same json obejct as property

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you are right, but some times you don'e have another choise.

Comment: How many *unique* objects are there? (If there's a reasonable amount, like less than 100,000 or so, then `sort`ing is possible without taking too long. Otherwise, will have to find a less complex way to retrieve the top 10) I have a `.sort` solution but I'm worried it would take too long

Comment: @CertainPerformance got you. but I am not sure as I am getting this json from live server. so everytime it gets updates. though we can use `sort` function. I am saying this because I will improve it later, right now What I am in need is that proper way. and thanks for looking into this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the data into an object that holds the count of each item, indexed by the stringified item. Then, if there aren't an reasonably huge number of unique objects, you can `sort` the entries by their number of occurrences, and then slice the first 10.

```js
var jsonData = [    
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "#5"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "#1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "#2"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "#8"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "#1"
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "#10" 
  },  
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "#2"
  }];
 const counts = jsonData.reduce((a, obj) => {
  const string = JSON.stringify(obj);
  a[string] = (a[string] || 0) + 1
  return a;
}, {});
const result = Object.entries(counts)
  .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
  .slice(0, 10)
  .map(([string, count]) => ({ count, obj: JSON.parse(string) }));
console.log(result);
```

To add the counts to the original data, iterate over the data once the `counts` object is constructed:

```js
var jsonData = [    
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "#5"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "#1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "#2"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "#8"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "#1"
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "#10" 
  },  
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "#2"
  }];
 const counts = jsonData.reduce((a, obj) => {
  const string = JSON.stringify(obj);
  a[string] = (a[string] || 0) + 1
  return a;
}, {});
jsonData.forEach((item) => {
  item.count = counts[JSON.stringify(item)];
});
console.log(jsonData);
```

Comment: hey @certainPerformance, this actually worked. I am getting what I expected. thank you very much.

Comment: cool solution, not taking much time as compared to my code which I was doing earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I created one logic and it is working. 
The steps are as follows :

- **Sort the array based on the name**
- **Read the sorted array and count the number of name appearing
  continuously and store the count number**
- **Sort again based on the number of count**

Sample code is attached. Please take a look at the final result.

```js
var jsonData = [    
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "#5"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "#1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "#2"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "#8"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "#1"
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "#10" 
  },  
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "#2"
  }];    
   
  
  
  $('#output1').html(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  
 jsonData.sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0)
  
  $('#output2').html(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  
  let newArray= [];
  
   let total = 1;
for(let i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){
 let nextName = (i==jsonData.length -1)?0 : jsonData[i+1].name;
    let currentName = jsonData[i].name;
    
    if(nextName != currentName){
      newArray.push({
       id : jsonData[i].id,
        name : currentName,
        count : total
      });
    total = 1;
      }
      else{
       total+=1;
      }
  }
  
  $('#output3').html(JSON.stringify(newArray));
  
  //Lets sort it again based on count and take the top 10
  
newArray.sort((a, b) => a.count > b.count ? -1 : a.count < b.count ? 1 : 0)

newArray = newArray.slice(0, 10); // Here is your Data

$('#output4').html(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="output1">

</p>
<p id="output2">

</p>
<p id="output3">

</p>
<p id="output4">

</p>
```